# How to transpose columns to row in excel?

Tags: excel, transpose

I have a data like this:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnrLi.png)

I would like to transpose my data that currently looks like this:

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCCc0.png)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just a one-time operation you can use Unpivot. Depending on your Excel version the commands name may differ, but the logic is:

- select your data and click `Insert` -> `Table`
- right-click in the new table and click `Get & Transform` (this may be called in many different ways)
- a PowerQuery window opens
- select the columns you want to unpivot (column3, 4, and 5 in your example)
- right-click and select `Unpivot selected columns`
- click `Close and Load`

You're done.

Of course if you have to do the transposition many times then you may want to use VBA to automate the job.